# Automate the Boring Stuff - Coin Flip Streaks - How to optimize my answer?

Tags: python

I've been going through automate the boring stuff, and am trying the practice problems.
I came up with this solution to the project on the lists chapter - Coin Flip Streaks.

The objective of the problem is the following:
''For this exercise, we’ll try doing an experiment. If you flip a coin 100 times and write down an “H” for each heads and “T” for each tails, you’ll create a list that looks like “T T T T H H H H T T.” If you ask a human to make up 100 random coin flips, you’ll probably end up with alternating head-tail results like “H T H T H H T H T T,” which looks random (to humans), but isn’t mathematically random. A human will almost never write down a streak of six heads or six tails in a row, even though it is highly likely to happen in truly random coin flips. Humans are predictably bad at being random.

Write a program to find out how often a streak of six heads or a streak of six tails comes up in a randomly generated list of heads and tails. Your program breaks up the experiment into two parts: the first part generates a list of randomly selected 'heads' and 'tails' values, and the second part checks if there is a streak in it. Put all of this code in a loop that repeats the experiment 10,000 times so we can find out what percentage of the coin flips contains a streak of six heads or tails in a row. As a hint, the function call random.randint(0, 1) will return a 0 value 50% of the time and a 1 value the other 50% of the time.''
And this is my code.

```
numberOfStreaks = 0
experiment = []
n = 0
for experimentNumber in range(1000):
    experimentNumber = experimentNumber + 1
    for test in range(100):
        selector = random.randint(0,1)
        if selector == 0:
            experiment = experiment + ['H']
        elif selector == 1:
            experiment = experiment + ['T']
    
    for n in range(94):
        if experiment[n:n+6] == ['T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T']:
            numberOfStreaks = numberOfStreaks + 1
        elif experiment[n:n+6] == ['H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H']:
            numberOfStreaks = numberOfStreaks + 1
        else:
            numberOfStreaks = numberOfStreaks
print((numberOfStreaks / 100000) * 100)
```

I can only run this solution efficiently for 1000 experiments, and the book says to run for 10000, but it takes too long.
I think this derives from the inneficiency of the algorithm I came up with.

How do I make this algorithm more efficient?

Comment: Hello! Welcome to stack overflow. Can you briefly describe what the question is, and the objective of the algorithm you're referencing. Also, It appears some edit's have been suggested by members of the community. You may want to consider applying some of those edit's to the upload.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here ? A link to the problem or, at the very least, the problem itself would be helpful to understand what you're looking to accomplish here. Are there any particular requirements here ?

Comment: for one thing, you don't need to increment your loop index `experimentNumber` within the loop.  There are also much better ways to fill your list like list comprehension, or there may even be a function within the random module to do it for you.

Comment: You could halve time time by combining both for loops.. Check for streaks each time you flip the coin rather than flipping all coins and checking again at the end.

Comment: The question and some of the answers show the ambiguity of what the problem statement is, and what the solution is.  Is it fair to paraphrase it as:  How many times will I get a streak of 6 or more heads or tails in 100 flips?  So it doesn't matter how many streaks occured in that set of 100 flips?  I think @Jacques Gaudin has that solution in his answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would write this:

```
import random

n_exp = 10_000
n_streak = 0
for experiment in range(n_exp):
    draw = ''.join(random.choices('HT', k=100))
    if 'H'*6 in draw or 'T'*6 in draw:
        n_streak += 1

res = n_streak / n_exp * 100
print(res)
```

The `random.choices` function builds a string of length 100 with random characters picked in `'HT'`, then you count the number of non-overlapping repetitions of a substring with 6 `H` or 6 `T`, add it to the number of streaks.

Comment: You could optimize it further by getting `'H'*6` and `'T'*6` out of the loop. Store them in a var and use the var or write it out fully in place 'HHHHHH' and 'TTTTTT'.

Comment: Well it is indeed very efficient... But it consistently returns `0.` because it searches strings of 6 characters in a list of 100 strings of only 1 character! IHMO having a sensible result should be more important than optimizing ;-) And please do not blindly join the list if you do not want probabilities greater that 1... You do compute a value but failed to wonder what it was actually measuring.

Comment: @SergeBallesta Thanks for checking, I made some corrections. I thought `choices` was doing the join operation for some reason.

Comment: Thanks for the the answer, but the book has not covered what the 'join' operation does yet

Answer (score 1):

If the question is what I paraphrased in my comment, this is about as efficient as you can be. (Notice that once a streak is seen, that trial is over before 100 coins were flipped)

```
import random
EXPERIMENT_COUNT = 10_000
streaks = 0
random.seed()  # make sure each run is different
for trials in range(EXPERIMENT_COUNT):
    heads = tails = 0
    for flips in range(100):
        if random.choice((False,True)):
            heads += 1
            tails = 0
        else:
            tails += 1
            heads = 0
        if heads >= 6 or tails >= 6:
            streaks += 1
            break
print (f"In {EXPERIMENT_COUNT} trials of 100 flips, {streaks} trials contained a streak of 6 or more")
print (f"Which is about {streaks*100 // EXPERIMENT_COUNT}%")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify it by only having one for loop, this also removes the need to append to a list and speeds things up a lot. (10000 in < 1second)

```
import random

numberOfStreaks = 0
experiment = []
n = 0
for experimentNumber in range(1000):
    heads=0
    tails=0
    
    for test in range(100):
        
        if random.randint(0,1):
            heads += 1
            tails = 0
        else:
            tails += 1
            heads = 0

        if heads >= 6 or tails >= 6:
            numberOfStreaks += 1
            
print((numberOfStreaks / 100000) * 100)
```

Comment: By resetting the counters the way you are, this doesn't give the same answer as the original algorithm.  For example, 8 heads in a row should be counted as 3 streaks (overlapping).

Comment: Good point, you can omit that. Changed it to match the original example

Comment: Upon rereading the question, it seems like what is really wanted is the number of 100-flip trials that contain at least one streak.  See my proposed answer.

Answer (score 0):

We should first wonder what is the actual quantity that we want to establish. Here the text says (emphasize mine):

> Write a program to find out **how often** a streak of six heads or a streak of six tails comes up in a randomly generated list of heads and tails. Your program breaks up the experiment into two parts: the first part generates a list of randomly selected 'heads' and 'tails' values, and the second part **checks if there is a streak in it**. Put all of this code in a loop that repeats the experiment 10,000 times so we can find out what **percentage** of the coin flips contains a streak of six heads or tails in a row.

As we want a percentage computed on 10000 experiment, it means that each experiment shall be true if it contains *at least* a streak, and false if it does not.

Applying minimum changes to the code proposed by @JeffUK, it could be

```
import random

numberOfStreaks = 0
experiment = []
n = 0
for experimentNumber in range(1000):
    heads=0
    tails=0
    
    for test in range(100):
        
        if random.randint(0,1):
            heads += 1
            tails = 0
        else:
            tails += 1
            heads = 0

        if heads == 6 or tails == 6:
            numberOfStreaks +=1
            break   # stop after first match!
            
print((numberOfStreaks / 100000) * 100)
```

And the result should be around 80, meaning that the probability of having at least one sequence of 6 identical flip when we launch it 100 time is close to 80%

Comment: Wow...thanks! It turns out I hadn't even understood what they were asking, and trying to find how probable it was for those strings to appear instead

Answer (score 0):

```
import random 

lst = ['H','T']
lst_final = []
cnt = 0 
x = 10000

for i in range(x):
    lst_final.append(random.choice(lst))

str1 = ''.join(lst_final)

for i in range(len(str1)-1):
    if (str1[i] == 'H' and str1[i+1] == 'H') or (str1[i] == 'T' and str1[i+1] == 'T'):
            cnt += 1 

perc = (cnt/x)*100 
print(cnt, perc)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).